# Tax benefits with non working spouse while on L1 visa?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I’m moving to California on an L1 visa soon. My wife will also be traveling with me. We have the following in mind:

- She travels to US with me.
- Applies for the EAD work permit and comes back to India.
- Resumes her job in India until she actually gets the work permit.
- Once she get’s the work permit, she quits her job in India, travels
  back to the US, and tries to find a job there.

I have 2 questions:

1. What tax benefits do I get if I have a non working spouse ?
2. Do I get these benefits for the duration that she is not in the US but back
   in our native country and has a job there ?

Answer (score -1):

> What tax benefits do I get if I have a non working spouse ?

None

> Do I get these benefits for the duration that she is not in the US but back in our native country and has a job there ?

N/A

Comment: I thought you can claim her as a dependant? I do that.

Comment: @Aganju how does her employment status affect your claiming her as a dependent?

Comment: @Aganju: A spouse can never be a dependent. You can file jointly with your spouse. Or, if you file separately, you can claim an exemption for your spouse if your spouse doesn't file and doesn't have income.